# Extracting PDF from Apache Solr

Tags: indexing, solr

I am new to Solr indexing. I used Solr 5.5 and indexed a pdf file in it by simply using

```
#bin/post -c gettingstarted /home/ubuntu/pdf.pdf
```

I deleted the source pdf file. Is there anyway I can extract the pdf file from Apache Solr. I can see it is indexed from the URL

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/select?q=*.pdf
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it indexed properly by default pdf content is indexed into field name `content` if it declared in schema correctly. so search some keyword (or *) using that content field.

Ex:
`q=content:keyword`  (keyword -> which is present in pdf)

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/select?q=content:*
```

If `contetnt` field is undefined. then add field definition in schema file.

Ex: Field name declaration

```
<field name="content" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

Field Type defintion

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Comment: I indexed pdf like this 
`bin/post -c gettingstarted /home/ubuntu/pdf.pdf`

`http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/select?q=content` showing same results as `q=*.pdf`. 

`http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/select?q=content:*` giving error with code 404. 

Any suggestion please.

Comment: That probably indicates that you do not have a content field. Search with `*:*` and apply the necessary `fq` to find your doc.

Comment: what error you getting.? as I mentioned before and @BinoyDalal  said `content` field might not be defined in your schema file. check for that. I guess You didn't index pdf correctly.

Comment: Thanks guys for the replies. 
I actually didn't modify schema at all. I simply indexed pdf file using `post` command and I can query anything from that pdf file. 
That's the error if I run `q=content:*`....
`<lst name="error">
<lst name="metadata">
<str name="error-class">org.apache.solr.common.SolrException</str>
<str name="root-error-class">org.apache.solr.common.SolrException</str>
</lst>
<str name="msg">undefined field content</str>
<int name="code">400</int>
</lst>
</response>`

Comment: `undefined field content` this error shows your schema don't have content field. you should add field definition for `content` in schema file. then it works fine. I updated answer for your reference.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I had to add `content` field in schema as well as I needed to change the way I was indexing. I Indexed like this `http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/update?stream.body=<add><doc><field name="id">/root/sample10.pdf</field><field name="content">The pdf995 suite of products</field></doc></add>&commit=true` and content is showing the string now. Thanks.